# Rotate marker on Google Maps using ObjectAnimator in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, objectanimator

I was referring to this code snippet to animate marker on Google Maps, which uses ObjectAnimator. I call the method again once it ends, providing it with new value from a list.

```
public class MarkerAnimation {
static GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> _trips = new ArrayList<>() ;
Marker _marker;
LatLngInterpolator _latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical();

public void animateLine(ArrayList<LatLng> Trips,GoogleMap map,Marker  marker,Context current){
    _trips.addAll(Trips);
    _marker = marker;

animateMarker();
}

public void animateMarker() {
    TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
        @Override
        public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
            return _latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
        }
    };
    Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");

    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(_marker, property, typeEvaluator, _trips.get(0));

    //ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.o(view, "alpha", 0.0f);
    animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            //  animDrawable.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            //  animDrawable.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            //  animDrawable.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            //  animDrawable.stop();
            if (_trips.size() > 1) {
                _trips.remove(0);
                animateMarker();
            }
        }
    });

    animator.setDuration(300);   
    animator.start();
}
```

ObjectAnimator is best suited for my needs, and I would like to know if I can smoothly rotate a (car) marker using it.